# Android MapView keeps Location on

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a simple fragment with a mapview displayed. I have override all the necessary methods according to the documentation (destroy, resume and start) to cal the same method of the mapview. However when I detach the fragment or exit the application the location keeps on. It will drain too much battery. Is there any procedure I can make to stop the location feature?. I've tried calling mapview.onDestroy, mapview=null, etc etc and the location keeps on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [How to unregister Listener & stop service from within broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786849/how-to-unregister-listener-stop-service-from-within-broadcastreceiver). If you're using LocationManager to get location updates, call removeUpdates(getActivity()) on your LocationManager instance to stop them.

Edit as requested:
Searching the current location via GPS is disabled by calling setMyLocationEnabled(false) on the GoogleMap instance.

Comment: No i'm not using LocationManager. Not even LocationClient. I'm just displaying a map and then removing it.

Comment: Then there's actually no way it will "keep on" and drain your battery. Otherwise I'm confused, what is "location keeps on" supposed to mean?

Comment: After I click map https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxnlc4bu46fcpg2/device-2014-08-12-112616.png . After I exit the application https://www.dropbox.com/s/yb2958qfm5upu3w/device-2014-08-12-112644.png . Notice the location Icon... Result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4gwxcde2yggso6/device-2014-08-12-112847.png

Comment: Sorry, can't access those screenshots. But I think I know what you mean: The "searching location via GPS"-icon. In that case, try calling setMyLocationEnabled(false) immediately on your map. If that doesn't work either, it's a device specific problem and shouldn't bother you.

Comment: setMyLocationEnabled(false) did the job. Edit your original post and I'll mark as answer. Thanks